# Error 100 MongoDB 3.4.4

Tags: mongodb

> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.724-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9476 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=ArianWhite
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.726-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.726-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: windows-64
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.727-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>
> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, instalé `MongoDB 3.4.4` y me salen los errores anteriores, estoy tratando de ejecutar mongod para iniciar los servicios, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Comment: trata poniendo `dbpath=C:\data\db`

Comment: Lo siento, podrías ser un poco mas específico, ¿eso lo coloco en la terminal, o creo el directorio? o en alguna parte al ejecutar mongoDB

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate en la línea:

> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating

1. Verifica que `c:datadb` existe. Es el directorio en el cual mongo almacenas la base de datos.
2. Verifica que ese directorio tiene los permisos suficientes para poder escribir en el.
3. En linux existe el fichero de lock en `/var/lib/mongo/mongo.lock`. Busca en Windows si existe tal fichero y bórralo.

Comment: No existe esa carpeta, no en C:, también había leído acerca del el archivo mongo.lock, pero en windows no está ese archivo, o no al menos en la versión 3.4.4 de Mongo

Comment: En windows deberías tener el fichero C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg que es el fichero de configuración de mongo.
La variable dbpath  indica el directorio donde la instancia de base de datos almacena toda su información.

El valor de esa variable debería ser, según el error que nos indicas, c:\data\db, pero efectivamente no tendrás allí las bdd.

Dinos qué valor indica la variable

Answer (score 0):

> 2017-04-24T23:51:45.728-0500 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating

Solo tienes que crear el los siguientes folders: data y db, estando en C:

```
C:\> mkdir data\db
```

Esté es el tutorial de los pasos necesarios para ejecutar mongod en windows: [Set up the MongoDB environment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#set-up-the-mongodb-environment)